# Xcode 6 Provision Profile Selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, provisioning-profile

I want to create .ipa file. With Xcode 5 it was extremely easy.
But now Xcode 6 don't see (or don't want to see) my profiles and create them by itself.

So I point my profile here

[image]

Click Archive > Export > Ad Hoc > Choose my team
and every time I got this at last step...

[image]

I tried to delete all profiles, to recreate profiles, to restart Xcode and reArchive project. Nothing works. I need help, please.

Thanks :)

Comment: Go to the [provisioning profiles page in member centre](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action) and edit that XC Ad Hoc profile to include the devices you want, then just distribute with that profile instead.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem too.

I found a workaround for this that works for me. I installed both Xcode6.1 and Xcode 5.1. Then I used Xcode 6.1 to build and create the archive, and used Xcode 5.1.1 to submit.